# Spring MVC default GET request parameter binding to command type

Tags: spring-mvc, binding, get, controller

As I read [explanation](http://www.jpalace.org/docs/technotes/spring/mvc-params.html) here, I found that Spring can automatically bind GET request parameter to a type. Below is the sample code from the link.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {
        ...             
        @RequestMapping("/create")
        public String create(Person p) {
                //TODO: add Person to DAO
                return "person/show";
        }
}
```

Can someone tell me how spring do this? What bean that contains the logic to convert the parameter onto command type (Person type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is done here: [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor#resolveArgument()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html#resolveArgument%28org.springframework.core.MethodParameter,%20org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer,%20org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,%20org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory%29)

This is the excerpt of code where it actually binds the class to the values:

```
String name = ModelFactory.getNameForParameter(parameter);
//Here it determines the type of the parameter and creates an instance
Object attribute = (mavContainer.containsAttribute(name)) ?
            mavContainer.getModel().get(name) : createAttribute(name, parameter, binderFactory, request);

//Then it binds the parameters from the servlet to the previously created instance
WebDataBinder binder = binderFactory.createBinder(request, attribute, name);
if (binder.getTarget() != null) {
    bindRequestParameters(binder, request);
    validateIfApplicable(binder, parameter);
    if (binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors()) {
        if (isBindExceptionRequired(binder, parameter)) {
            throw new BindException(binder.getBindingResult());
        }
    }
}
```